# Помогите решить проблему с Unity/Android

Tags: unity3d

Выдает такую ошибку: UnityException: JDK not found Java Development Kit (JDK) directory is not set or invalid. Please, fix it in Preferences...
Я смотрел как ее устранить, сказали докачать модуль Android, скачал. Но все равно выдает эту ошибку.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У Вас бесплатная юнити, или крякнутая профессиональная? Проверьте, правильно ли у Вас указан путь к JDK в настрйках (Edit-Preferences-External Tools-JDK Installed)

Answer (score 0):

Зайдите в `Edit` > `Preferences` > `External Tools` и проверьте, стоит ли галочка на JDK, если нет то пропишите заново путь.

Какая у Вас версия движка Unity?
У меня была подобная проблема на 2021.1.16f1, запустил на 2021.1.15f1 и ошибка пропала.

Answer (score 0):

Я сталкивался с подобной проблемой, вот что я делал для решения данной проблемы:

1. Создание переменной JAVA_HOME(если она есть, то можно попробовать прописать путь к JDK в ручную). Для создания мы переходим в "Мой компьютер" >> "Свойства" >> "Дополнительные параметры системы" >> "Переменные среды" >> "Создать" (создаем и прописываем путь к JDK)
   2.Переходим в Unity >> "Assets" >> "External Dependency Manager" >> "Android Resolver" >> "Force Resolve"

После выполнения данных действий мой проект собрался без каких-либо ошибок.